# Authorize.net AKAMAI NETWORK update With Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

Is anyone else aware of the AKAMAI NETWORK change with authorize.net, and receiving their annoying emails claiming we need to adjust our websites to be on this update?

I run magento sites. Is there anything that needs to be done? Has anyone experienced this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am also aware of this and found this awesome article:
http://www.envalo.com/magento-authorize-net-technical-update/

In my case, our store uses a different extension for Authorize.NET, so I am trying to contact them to check if they will update their extensions.

But, in summary, if you use the native Authorize.NET setup in Magento, just change the URL's as explained in the article.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the notice and changes in question: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Important-Authorize-Net-Networking-Change/ba-p/51272

As the notice explains, the upcoming cutover (happening June 30, 2016) is when the existing API endpoint (`api.authorize.net`) will be changed from the current direct connection to use Akamai (as `api2.authorize.net` already does).

You can change your sites to the new endpoint ahead of time if you'd like. It'll keep working past June 30, and that gets you the touted reliability advantages of Akamai in the mean time. The standard Authorize.Net gateway has a setting for it you need to change, nothing more.

As far as whether it will affect you: It's unlikely any web server will be affected by the change unless they're running a fairly unusual environment, particularly regarding DNS and outgoing firewall. You can test the sandbox or `api2.authorize.net`, but chances are it will work fine. And if that's the case, the June 30 changeover should be completely seamless for you, even if you don't change your endpoint or settings at all.

Plugin note, since we've gotten a lot of questions about it too: ParadoxLabs' Authorize.Net CIM extension uses the Akamai URL by default as of version 2.2.0 (Oct 2015). If you're using it, you probably already have the change--just make sure you're up to date.

tl;dr: For all the noise they've made, you're probably fine. You can test to be sure.